# Shorter version of calculation

Tags: java, algorithm, math

I have two methods, that I believe can be made better way, but can't find this way.

First:

```
public int calcPow(long num) {
   int count = 0;
   while(num/2!=0) {
       num = num/2;
       count++;
   }
   return count;
}
```

The second is:

```
private long findParentNumber(long value) {
    for(int bitNum = 0; bitNum < Long.SIZE; bitNum++) {
        if((value & (1L << bitNum)) != 0) {
           return value ^ (1L << bitNum);
        }
    }
    throw new RuntimeException("No parent number found");
}
```

I believe, there are ways to do the same without loops. Can you help?

Cheers!

Comment: What's wrong with loops? You can try to replace the loops with recursive methods.

Comment: @Eran but that is more dangerous and a bit more space consuming

Comment: Could you explain what the second function achieves?

Comment: When there is an easier way why not make use of it? 

Far more computing sins are committed in the name of efficiency (without necessarily achieving it) than for any other single reason - including blind stupidity. - William A. Wulf

Answer (score 4):

For the second one, you're unsetting the lowest set bit. There's a relatively well known bithack to do that, though only relatively because it seems that bithacks in general are not well known.

Anyway, it's

```
return x & (x - 1);
```

The logic here is that in `x - 1`, there's a borrow running through the lowest zeroes until it hits the lowest 1-bit, which it unsets. The lowest zeroes are left set, they are then removed by ANDing it with the original number.

You can write the first one in terms of `numberOfLeadingZeros`, which would be more obviously correct than floating point hacks which always make you think about how accurate they might be (and in any case they're slow, you might be better off with the loop).

Edit: for completeness, that would be `63 - numberOfLeadingZeros(x)`, it differs from your definition at `x = 0` but that's a bad input anyway.

Comment: Upvoted, this is nice, and portable to C and C++ too.

Comment: Thanks, tested this and it is OK. Very good solution.

Answer (score 3):

Try this for the first one.

```
public int calcPow(long num) {
    if (num == 0) return 0;
    if (num < 0) num = -num;
    return Long.numberOfTrailingZeros(Long.highestOneBit(num));
}
```

Or this [suggested by harold](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40130249/shorter-version-of-calculation/40130861#40130548)

```
public int calcPow(long num) {
    return num == 0 ? 0
        : 63 - Long.numberOfLeadingZeros(Math.abs(num));
}
```

Comment: This is short and the fastest solution. Thanks.

Comment: @CD I agree, though I would prefer it if Ternaries were used for the first two lines. I think it would look better. Like `return num == 0? 0: Long.numberOfTrailingZeros(Long.highestOneBit(num < 0)? num * -1: num);` or use `Math.abs()`

Answer (score 2):

For the first one, you can use the `Math.log` method that already exists:

```
public static int log2(long number) {
    return (int) Math.floor(Math.log(number) / Math.log(2));
}
```

or this faster function [suggested by saka1029](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40130249/shorter-version-of-calculation/40130861#40130861):

```
public static int log2(long number) {
    return number == 0? 0: Long.numberOfTrailingZeros(Long.highestOneBit((number < 0)? number * -1: number));
}
```

As you can see I also changed the method to static, since I see no point in having to use an Object to get a log when no object is involved. And secondly I changed the names into something more fitting.

For the second one you can use the bit-wise check operator `&`:

```
public static long removeSmallBit(long value) {
    return value & (value - 1);
}
```

Essentially you are removing the smallest bit from the variable, and return that number after you change that bit to 0. And as you can see again I made the method static and changed the name. 2nd answered inspired by [this answer submitted by harold](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40130249/shorter-version-of-calculation/40130548#40130548)

Comment: I *think* it's ceil due to the way the integer division operates.

Comment: Actually you were the first to get this correct; have an upvote!

Comment: Yes, It is working! Thanks a lot